# Does convergence of moment implies existence of finite moment?

Tags: convergence, moments

Let $X_n$ by a random variable that converges in distribution to $X$. On the top of that,

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_n] = E[X] = O(1).$$

Does it implies that for every $n$

$$ E[X_n] < \infty? $$

Comment: (1) The "$=O(1)$" part makes no sense.  (2) Your question is about the sequence of numbers $a_n = E[X_n].$ It's not about random variables.  It asks only if, when a limit of (possibly infinite or undefined) values $a_n$ equals a (possibly infinite or undefined value), whether the $a_n$ must be finite.